# Maven execute two modules sequentially

Tags: maven, tycho

I have two maven projects:

- One builds a few OSGi bundles and creates a local p2 repository containing them
- The other builds an Eclipse plugin with tycho using these bundles

When I execute them separately, everything works: the first execution creates the repository, and the second can use it.

But I want to create a single pom executing both. The simple approach:

```
<modules>
    <module>p2-repository-generator</module>
    <module>tycho-project</module>
</modules>
```

Doesn't work, because tycho tries to use the repository generated by the first pom even before it exists [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013169/how-does-tycho-bind-its-goals-to-the-maven-lifecycle).

Can I execute two maven tasks sequentially using maven, without external tools? Or can I delay tycho's dependency hook to a later point in the build?

To clarify:

- `tycho-project` depends on `p2-repository-generator`, so it is executed after it.
- but Tycho uses a custom [lifecycle participant](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/core/maven/TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java), which tries to resolve p2 dependencies with an `afterProjectsRead` callback - which is too soon, since the p2 repository will be there only after `p2-repository-generator` built it.
- This aggretor works after I execute `p2-repository-generator` once manually, because then `tycho-project` is able to find the p2 repository generated by it

Comment: For reference: There are [plans to make Tycho not already resolve dependencies in afterProjectsRead](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353889) but it'll still take a while to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noted, Tycho does things very early in the build, which leads to problems if you generate content in the same build to be used by the Tycho build. A workaround for this problem is to wrap the part of the build using Tycho in a [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html) call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting a dependency on `p2-repository-generator` for `tycho-project`? IMHO it should enforce a build sequence you need here.

Comment: Yes, it depends on it. But tycho implements its dependency resolution using `AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant::afterProjectsRead`, which is executed immediately after maven parses that module, not after it's dependencies were built.